# How my controllers update the scope variable of other controller?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have written a code where I wanted a Service which returns promise.
Now this service I injected in two controllers, these controllers are not scope inherited in view, but than too once I update a model value in controller 1, that updated value gets reflected on controller 2. How come ?

Please follow the code below,

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="MyApp">
<head>
    <title>Recipe 02 example 01</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="D:\Rahul Shivsharan\JavaScript-Framework\AngularJS\angular.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="D:\Rahul Shivsharan\JavaScript-Framework\jQuery\jquery-1.11.1.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="D:\Rahul Shivsharan\JavaScript-Framework\BootstrapCSS\bootstrap-3.2.0-dist\js\bootstrap.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="D:\Rahul Shivsharan\JavaScript-Framework\BootstrapCSS\bootstrap-3.2.0-dist\css\bootstrap.css"></link>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="D:\Rahul Shivsharan\JavaScript-Framework\BootstrapCSS\bootstrap-3.2.0-dist\css\bootstrap-theme.css"></link>
    <script type="text/javaScript">
        angular.module("MyApp",[]);
        (function(){
            angular.module("MyApp").controller("myCtrlOne",myCtrlOne)
                                   .controller("myCtrlTwo",myCtrlTwo);

            function myCtrlOne(storedValue){
                var obj = this;                 
                obj.myVal = undefined;

                storedValue.get().then(function(value){
                    obj.myVal = value;
                });

            };

            function myCtrlTwo(storedValue){
                var obj = this;
                obj.myVal = undefined;

                storedValue.get().then(function(value){
                    obj.myVal = value;
                });
            };


        })();

        (function(){
            angular.module("MyApp").factory("storedValue",storedValue);

            function storedValue($q){
                var obj = { get : fn },
                    promise = undefined;

                return obj;

                function fn(){
                    return promise || getData();

                    function getData(){
                        promise = $q.when({
                            label : 'Hello',
                            value : 1000
                        });

                        return promise;
                    };
                };
            }
        })();
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div ng-controller="myCtrlOne as one">
        <h2>One</h2>
        <label for="">Stored Value:</label>{{one.myVal | json}} <br/>
        Value: <input  type='text' ng-model='one.myVal.value' />
    </div>



    <div ng-controller="myCtrlTwo as two">
        <h2>Two</h2>
        <label for="">Stored Value:</label>{{two.myVal | json}} <br/>
    </div>
</body>
```

Please refer the jsfiddle link below

[My Angular-Promise](http://jsfiddle.net/rahulshivsharan/prrdj8k2/2/)

I am confused.

Please guide me

Comment: thats what services are for.. for sharing same data among controller

Comment: same service is inside both controller and there is no input to service which means service is input independent so it is obvious that both will return the same data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is that you're you are caching the factory's result.

You can see usage of cache in line:

```
 return promise || getData();
```

The factory will run every time it is injected, but will return the cached promise.

Since this is an object, both controllers will point to  the same object.

added a print to your fiddle. open the console to see that "getting data" is printed only once.

http://jsfiddle.net/3hb0acdk/

```
function getData(){
    console.log('getting data');
    promise = $q.when({
    label : 'Hello',
    value : 1000
});
```

Here is a fiddle that will generate 2 different objects and thus one won't affect the other

http://jsfiddle.net/d0queaat/

```
function fn(){
    return getData();

    function getData(){
        console.log('getting data');
        var promise = $q.when({
            label : 'Hello',
            value : 1000
        });

        return promise;
    };
};
```

Comment: But I have not added any setter method in the object returned by service, so how come the value gets updated in service ?

Comment: @RahulShivsharan - that's how pointers work.. there is only one object - everyone are looking at the same one. there's no "service object" and "controller object".. it is the same object.

Comment: @RahulShivsharan if you want to generate multiple objects, I think you should use providers. not sure about it. see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15666048/service-vs-provider-vs-factory

Comment: You can generate multiple objects with a factory too. Besides, JS is pass by value.

Comment: @skubski - objects are passed by reference. references are passed by value: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13104494/does-javascript-pass-by-reference

Comment: Yeah, I kinda double checked after I posted, I stand corrected. Nevertheless you can create new objects with a factory too.

Comment: @RahulShivsharan - skubski is right, my first answer is incorrect. the reason you're getting the same result is because you write: `return promise || getData();` .. I will edit it.. just a second.

Comment: @skubski - yes you are right. I was mistaken as well. I corrected my answer. thanks!